# Combine MIDI files

Tags: midi

I'm working on a project where we have a large number of MIDI files and want to combine them into new files with more notes. We want to combine them both in parallel, so that two combined files play at the same time and put their sounds on different tracks, and in series, so that one file plays its sequence, and then on the measure afterwards, the next MIDI file starts playing. Are there any tools or techniques to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't have specific experience, but I'd think just about any decent midi editor should be able to do what you are talking about so long as you aren't pushing it beyond the maximum number of tracks supported by Midi standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a DAW such as Cubase (or any other similar). This has functions to import your MIDI files which allow you to split the embedded tracks (based on channels).

You will then get the note data spread to multiple tracks and can move them around as any clip. Assign a sound to the track and you're good to go.

You can finally export your project as a new MIDI file.

Comment: Aria Meastosa is a lightwieght and open-source MIDI editor to get this job done if you don't have DAWs abailable. http://ariamaestosa.sourceforge.net/ (I was on a team where I was the only one with composing experience, but we needed to work on MIDI files for software development.)

Comment: @Kevin nice! I will for one check out your project.

Answer (score 0):

between **Musescore** and **Audacity**, combining and time-phasing *should* be easy and *definitely* cost you only the time it takes to learn the two interfaces.